# Do I have to replace the mock with concrete implementation?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tdd

I have written a unit test with mocking the dependencies of the controller after that I have the real implementation of these dependencies, so should I replace the mock with the concrete implementation?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If you use the real dependencies, you may end up with an integration test rather than a unit test. These can be valuable, too, but since they are usually much slower and more brittle, I'd recommend focusing on the unit tests and only using a few integration tests.

Comment: Actually I'm asking if I have to do that ? because what I'm doing now is just testing the controller.
for example, if I want to test a method in my controller that creates or deletes an object from the database, I want to be able to do that because the part of code responsible for that task is mocked

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your question is, but it sounds as though you've written a test of a Controller using [Test Doubles](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html), and now you'd also like to test the actual dependencies that the Controller is going to have in production.

If so, there's at least two options open to you:

- Test the dependencies in isolation
- Test the integration of Controller and its dependencies

There's value in both, and disadvantages as well. J.B. Rainsberger [creditably explains the problem with integration tests](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam), and I don't think you should put all of your eggs in that basket. The [test pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html) offers good guidance: Write most of your tests as unit tests, fewer as integration tests, and so on.

Thus, I suggest first testing the real implementations of the Controller's dependencies in isolation; i.e. not involving the Controller at all. Once you know that the dependencies work in isolation, a few integration tests may be in order, so that you demonstrate that they integrate well.

You should leave the test(s) you already wrote alone. [Tests are most trustworthy if you edit them as little as possible](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/02/why-trust-tests).